# Issue pushing symbol packages to Symbol Server

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015, symbol-server

I installed a Symbol Server (following this post: http://www.xavierdecoster.com/setting-up-your-own-symbolsource-server-step-by-step) and push symbol packages to that server. It has been worked so far. But then when I upgraded my machine to Windows 10 & Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition, I can't push my symbol packages (build with VS2015) to symbol server any more.

I've tried to search around but don't see any solution fit with my issue

This is the issue when I've tried to run push command:

```
nuget push *.symbols.nupkg 123 -Source http://[ip-address]:8082/nuget

Failed to process request. 'Package submission failed: Unknown custom metadata item kind: 6. See http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/Help for possible reasons. Fiddler may help diagnosing this error if your client discards attached detailed information.'.
The remote server returned an error: (506) Package submission failed: Unknown custom metadata item kind: 6. See http://www.symbolsourc
e.org/Public/Home/Help for possible reasons. Fiddler may help diagnosing this error if your client discards attached detailed information..
```

Comment: I've tried to install VS2013 again and it works for now. Still don't understand why it has issue with VS2015.

Comment: Same behavior for me.

Comment: Same issue here! Any idea if there is a fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to the new tooling introduced in VS2015, which is being built to support the new DNX package formats. You can read more about this [here](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/overview.html). VS2015 is using NuGet v3 rather than v2, see [this announcement](http://blog.nuget.org/20151008/NuGet-3-What-and-Why.html). I think it boils down the fact that the package format has changed so that it can support multiple frameworks within the same package.

There are similar issue on the [ASP.NET GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx) [here](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/1690) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnet5/issues/40).

I suspect that your Symbol Server is not capable of handling these new package types. My suggestion would be to either update to use a symbol server that supports the new package format, or look at using NuGet v2 to create and publish your packages.